# Flash As 2.0 How to edit actionscript for attached movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I have attached a movie clip on my flash project using `attachmovie()` method in AS2. Now i want to remove it when somebody clicks it using

```
on(press){
    this.removeMovieClip('mc1');
}
```

But I don't know how to add actionscript for attached movieclips. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
_root.attachMovie('mymovie','mc1',100); // your as identifier/movie clip name, depth

_root.mc1.onPress=function() {

        removeMovieClip(this);
}
```